# Is it OK to ask FTP connection questions here

Tags: support

I'm trying to get a file uploaded using FileZilla and for what ever reasons, can't.

Is this question on topic here?

Comment: Just as a friendly aside, if you control both endpoints **please please please** use something other than FTP.

Comment: @MDMarra That comment could have been so much more useful with examples of alternatives! :)

Comment: Anything with encryption :) FTP sends everything, including credentials, in plaintext.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kudos for asking, but unless you also run the FTP infrastructure you're trying to upload to then Server Fault is not for that question.

What I'd suggest you do is collect your FTP log and try over on superuser.com - their site is more suited to end-user questions.

Comment: OK. I'm running both sides here. The issue is I've written a .NET program to upload a file via FTP to my VPS. Dreamweaver connects via FTP fine, so the issue is either a set up on my VPS or my code. As it could be either, I was concerned about posting on SO incase they send me here or SU. Still try on SU?

Comment: In the circumstances you describe, controlling both ends of the connection, it's either here or SO.

Comment: Given that FTP works fine for Dreamweaver but not your code the question has to be programming related, which makes SO the clear-cut winner.

Comment: It did go on SU, simply because it worked with Dreamweaver and not with Windows Explorer! Thank you all